# Trying to filter out items from my state that are nested in my reducer

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

My state looks something like this:

```
{     
 "account":{  
    "id":7,    
    "categories":[  
       {  
          "id":7,          
          "products":[  
             {                  
                "productId":54                
             }
          ]
       },
       {  
          "id":9,          
          "products":[  
             {                  
                "productId":89                
             }
          ]
       }
    ]
 }
}
```

Now in my reducers I can return the current state like:

```
return {...state}
```

I can set a new value for account like:

```
return { ...state, account: action.account }
```

But how can I filter a nest item from the collection?

If I do this, my filter is returning back categories which is wrong as I want to return back an account:

```
return {...state, account: state.account.categories.filter((c) => c.id === 4)}
```

**If I do the above, instead of having an account value I have now set the account to a collection of categories.**

Can someone explain to me how I can get one level deeper i.e.
Set the account value to a new value by filtering the nested categories collection.

Comment: Is there an array of accounts somewhere? Not really clear what expected result is. Assume it is an object but you only show one `account` object

Comment: @charlietfl I want to remove e.g. category.id = 9.  How would I do that?  I'm not sure how to b/c it is nested.

Comment: So you want the `account`object  to only have a set of filtered `categories`?

Comment: @charlietfl I want to remove the category with id=9 from the account.categories collection in the redux state.  What I am currently doing is wrong because it assigns ```account``` to be a collection of categories.

Comment: So you have to filter that array separately and reassign to `categories` property. Or go through splicing....either way it will mutate original  `account` object

Comment: @charlietfl that is what I need help with, I am trying to filter it but not doing it correctly as you can see above.

Comment: Basic would be: `state.account.categories = state.account.categories.filter((c) => c.id === 4)}` but probably need to rebuild the object to prevent mutating original

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The challenge I think you're having is that you are muting your original source of data, and therefore are unable to apply another filter because the original data is lost.  To fix this, I would encourage you to create a 
new field to store the selected category.

```
return {
  ...state,
  account: {
    ...state.account, 
    selectedCategory: state.account.categories.find((c) => c.id === action.categoryId)
  }
}
```

Comment: the action will be:  action.categoryId so I will use that to filter. I won't have the account in the action.

Comment: Sounds like you'll need to store the account with all the categories into another state variable, then you can filter from there for the current selected category